# multiple chat rooms SignalR ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, chat

I've been doing a lot of reading, and everything seems either outdated or a little shy of enough for me.
So I've created a chat application based on [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

While I have something a little more advanced than that, for ease of use let's assume that's all that I have. How would you go from that to having multiple chat rooms and user authentication?

I've read some about groups, and I know asp.net has built in authentication, but I'm not sure what the best way to implement this is.

Right now I basically just parse their message on the client side and send it to the server to be posted on the screen of all the users. I also would like some persistent messaging, so if they get disconnected and reconnect they can still see the data, like sessions I guess.

I don't expect anyone to write my application, just some guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? Best of luck!

Comment: I actually haven't had a chance to look at this since I asked this question Thursday. I appreciate the answer and will definitely let you know how helpful it was once I have an opportunity to read/apply it!

Comment: I started working on this again today, your post was helpful thank you. I was trying to avoid DB interaction for as long as possible, but I guess it's pretty unavoidable.

Comment: oh but i should mention, i think a static datastructure is better for persistence in the same session and then sql for long term storage. otherwise the realtime aspect would be slower(i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the Authentication. SignalR basically comes on top of the usual ASP.NET authentication, so if you have an application with users, and roles (the basic MVC template is very good for this example - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security here you have all resources for MVC security, including some Pluralsight tutorials - you can have a hub that has an `Authorize` attribute, just like for controllers - http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization - here is the official documentation for hub authorization.

Basically, unless the user signs in, he can't:

1. Access the page with the chat. (because the controller is decorated with the `Authorize` attribute)
2. Access the hub server methods, because the entire hub - or some specific  methods are decorated with the `Authorize` attribute.

For the persistance part, you could use a SQL database to store the messages. (And since you have users in your application - that are stored by default in a SQL  database), it would be logical to use the same database to store your messages.

To wrap things up, fire up the MVC template with Individual User Accounts, add a new page with a controller that has the `Authorize` attribute,  create a hub  (or only some specific methods) with the `Authorize` attribute  and you are all set up.

You have a SignalR application that only authenticated users can use.

Hope this helps. Good luck!